# SpringBootTest failing - Why in single application test schema.sql and data.sql is executed twice?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

Hi I am writing a SpringBoot application, where I am writing unit as well as integration tests, but my integration tests are failing?

**Reason 1:** It tries to create a table by executing `schema.sql` twice and hence table already exists exception is thrown and the test fails.

**Reason 2:** Even if I put `create if not exists`, it fails on insertions by executing the `data.sql` as it tries to execute the script 2nd time and a uniqueness constraint violation occurs. I know I can drop tables or delete records at the start to get rid of errors.

> But why it's running twice? not thrice or once?

**First test**

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class Atest {

}
```

**Second test**

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class Btest {

}
```

**Third test**

```
@SpringBootTest
public class Ctest {

}
```

**Atest** and **Btest** both `passes` and they try to access a record from test data and they are able to see it.
but **Ctest** `fails` due to exception

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "tbl_test" already exists; SQL statement:
```

as there are 2 files in `test->resourece` folder `data.sql` and `schema.sql`. it tries to run them twice

**My Questions:**

1. Why Scripts are executed twice?
2. Why not thrice, once for each test?
3. I can see the only difference among them is `@SpringBootTest` vs `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)` but still they are in one execution cycle or context and hence it should not happen.
4. Why it does not fail when multiple tests have `@SpringBootTest` (like if all three has this annotaion).

Comment: Well without seeing the tests code it is kinda hard to see what the problem is

Comment: Because the context is different. One runs with a mock environment ht other with no web environment. Due to this difference it will load a new application context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

M. Deinum answered the question in his comment:

> Because the context is different. One runs with a mock environment ht other with no web environment. Due to this difference it will load a new application context.

To expand on this a little: The Spring testing infrastructure caches application contexts used for testing. If you use the same configuration for setting up the `ApplicationContext` in multiple tests, the `ApplicationContext` will be reused.

Since `ATest` and `BTest` use the same configuration they use the `ApplicationContext` instance. And since the execution of `schema.sql` and `data.sql` happens during construction of the `ApplicationContext` they get only executed once.

`CTest` uses a different configuration so the `ApplicationContext` has to get created freshly and therefore the scripts get executed again.